# JSON request is null when POSTing with WebClient but working with WebRequest, HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I have developed a Web API 2 application having the following Action

```
[Route("submit")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Submit([FromBody]Request request)
        {
            if (request != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Do Something
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return this.InternalServerError(ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return this.BadRequest("Request is null");
            }
        }
```

In my client application, if I use WebClient to call this action, the request object in the action is coming null.

**Using WebClient - Not Working**

```
private static void CallWebAPIUsingWebClient(string dataString, TokenResponse token, string url)
        {            
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                client.Headers.Add("Username", "WebClient");
                client.UploadString(url, "POST", dataString);
            }
        }
```

But, if i use WebRequest or HttpClient even, I am getting the complete request object in the action.

**Using WebRequest - Working**

```
private static void CallWebAPIUsingWebRequest(string dataString, TokenResponse token, string url)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Username", "WebRequest");

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(dataString);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

**Using HttpClient - Working**

```
private async static Task CallWebAPIUsingHttpClient(string dataString, TokenResponse token, string url)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", "HttpClient");
                await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(dataString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            }
        }
```

The strange thing is, even `WebClient` was working till yesterday.
Please let me know why, in particular, `WebClient` is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using `HTTPPUT` in the method below where as your original api controller action methods accepts `HTTPPOST`

```
private static void CallWebAPIUsingWebClient(string dataString, TokenResponse token, string middlewareUrl)
        {            
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = token.TokenType.ToLowerInvariant() + " " + token.AccessToken;
                client.Headers.Add("Username", "WebClient");
                client.UploadString(middlewareUrl, "PUT", dataString);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo in the question i posted, i updated my question.